# Sum results of a Select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I am trying to take the below query, and instead of getting all of the results for the query, I simply would like to output the sum of Amount by merchant_name by transaction_date (preferably by month).

Basically I would like to output a sum by merchant_name across dates rather than spit out every transaction/row from the below query.

```
SELECT  transaction_date ,
    merchant_name ,
    UNIQUE_MEM_ID ,
    Amount
FROM    table
    WHERE UNIQUE_MEM_ID IN(

SELECT  UNIQUE_MEM_ID
FROM    table
    WHERE (x = some criteria)
    AND Amount < 50
    )

GROUP BY transaction_date,
    merchant_name,
    UNIQUE_MEM_ID,
    Amount
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you would just phrase the query to do what you want:

```
SELECT transaction_date, merchant_name, SUM(Amount)
FROM table
WHERE UNIQUE_MEM_ID IN (SELECT UNIQUE_MEM_ID
                        FROM table
                        WHERE (x = some criteria) AND Amount < 50
                       )
GROUP BY transaction_date, merchant_name;
```